# python zeep and MessagePack attachments

Tags: python, zeep

A python rookie here and thank you for taking time to help.

I am sending a SOAP request to download some mp4 recordings from a server using zeep. The server responds by sending the following MessagePack attachments. How do I unpack this and convert to mp4. The multi-part attachment has both the decsription of the file and the actual MP4 file itself. Thanks

```
<MessagePack(attachments=[<Attachment('<6X3ER09X000X401BEFX91B4FFBD48906>', 'application/octet-stream')>, <Attachment('<0XECXX28CX0RS9DD28BYYA9F2CBA177D>', 'application/octet-stream')>])>
```

Here is the code I am trying to use

```
def get_record(client, siteid, username, passwd, ticket):
    return client.downloadNBRStorageFile(**{'siteId': 'xxxxx', 'recordId': xxxxx, 'ticket':ticket})

def main():

client = Client(wsdl=wsdl)
service = client.create_service(BINDING_NAME, ADDRESS)
resp = update_phone_by_name(service, siteid, username, password, ticket)
pack = client.service.downloadNBRStorageFile
recording = pack.root
description = pack.attachments[0].content
rec_file = pack.attachments[1].content
```

When I run this I get this error
"recording = pack.root
AttributeError: 'OperationProxy' object has no attribute 'root'"

I am trying to do the same as this post but unable to figure out how to download the attachments

[Python SOAP WSDL works in SOAPpy but not ZSI or zeep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445819/python-soap-wsdl-works-in-soappy-but-not-zsi-or-zeep)

----Edit-----Update-----
I have updated the code as below:

```
def get_ticket(client):
    global rec_ticket
    global ticket
    rec_ticket = client.getStorageAccessTicket(**{'siteId': siteid, 'username': username, 'password': password})
    return rec_ticket

def get_record(client):
    return client.downloadNBRStorageFile(**{'siteId': 'xxxxx', 'recordId':
```

recordid, 'ticket':rec_ticket})

```
def main():
    client = Client(wsdl=wsdl)
    axl = client.create_service(BINDING_NAME, ADDRESS)
    resp_ticket = get_ticket(axl)
    resp_rec = get_record(axl)
    pack = client.service.downloadNBRStorageFile(siteid, recordID, rec_ticket)

    record_details = pack.root
    record_file = pack.attachments[1].content
```

However I get the response below:
" raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.224.91.216', port=2001): Max retries exceeded with url: /nbr/services/NBRStorageService (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))"

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read through the zeep documentation?  There is some example code [in the docs](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/attachments.html).

Comment: Thanks larsks. I have looked at that doc but it does not help or I cant seem to understand how to apply it to this scenario. I have updatedmy question to include the code I am trying to use and the error I am getting

Comment: Can anyone please help out here.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually calling `client.service.downloadNBRStorageFile`.  To actually call the method, you would need:

```
pack = client.service.downloadNBRStorageFile()
```

(Note the parentheses on the end.)

Your current code is simply assigning the `client.service.downloadNBRStorageFile` object to your `pack` variable, which is why your error message refers to an `OperationProxy` type.

Comment: Thank you @larsks for taking time to help me on this. I modified the code as shown above but I just get connection timeout. NB if I remove the pack commands, the server responds with the messagePack attachments